# UIScrollView scrolling automatically by 64 points

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I'm adding a `UIScrollView` to a `UIViewController`s `view`. For some reason, between adding the scroll view to the view and it getting displayed, the `contentOffset` is set to `{0, -64}`, 64 being the status bar's 20 plus the navigation bar's 44 points (I guess). Below is some code that reproduces the issue, and an image.

How do I prevent iOS from setting the `contentOffset`?

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 100, 100)];
    _scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    _scroll.delegate = self;

    UIView *red = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
    red.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [_scroll addSubview:red];

    [self.view addSubview:_scroll];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // outputs {0, -64}
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(_scroll.contentOffset));
}
```

---

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is auto-layout on?  P.S. If you want a quick and dirty fairly universal solution, you could reset the content offset to CGPointZero in -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews .

Comment: no, I don't think. I'm not using storyboards and did not enable it on any views in code.

Comment: You don't need to be using storyboards to have auto-layout enabled; in fact, I think it's enable in xibs, by default.  To de-select it, open the .xib file, click on the first button above the menu on the right-hand side, then deselect the "Use Autolayout" button underneath the "Interface Builder Document" section.

Comment: Nonetheless, Dmitry's suggestion below is a good one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` on your view controller to `NO`, otherwise it'll adjust insets on the first subview of it's root view that happens to be of `UIScrollView` class.

More on this in [iOS 7 Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 11+, set UIScrollView's `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never` to prevent the system from adjusting `contentOffset` automatically when it's being added to another view